# React: how to refer to child of styled-component by its name

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is there a way to refer to sub-component of styled-component by its name? Or, besides passing hardcoded className and refer to it instead there's no way around it?

```
const Parent = styled.div`
  // some styles

  & > Child1 {
    opacity: 1;
  }

`;

const Child1 = styled.div`
  opacity: 0;
`;

const Child2 = styled.div`
  opacity: 0;
`;


const App = (props: Props) => (
  <Parent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
  </Parent>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm you have the `${}` missing in your styles. Also you might want to place the `const Parent` after declaring the `Child1`.

```
const Child1 = styled.div`
  opacity: 0;
`;

const Child2 = styled.div`
  opacity: 0;
`;

const Parent = styled.div`
  // some styles

  & > ${Child1} {
    opacity: 1;
  }

`;


const App = (props: Props) => (
  <Parent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
  </Parent>
)
```

If you wanna explore more about `template literals` here's a link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I see... I tried it before, but I declared child components after the Parent, so it did not work then.

Comment: So in JavaScript, you need to use a variable after you declare it. Unless it will be undefined. By default JavaScript put all the variables as undefined in it's context.